# After hashing the password using md5() and store it into database,cant login again

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

i built a login and registration system before,is running well.After I hash the input password using md5()and store it to the database,it cant login anymore.So everyone pls look at my code here,so i can know what goes wrong..here is my code here..

signup.php

```
include ('config.php');

$errors=array();   

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  $username=htmlentities($_POST['username']);
  $password=htmlentities($_POST['password']);
  $email=htmlentities($_POST['email']);
  $cpassword=htmlentities($_POST['cpassword']);
    //not empty
    //at least 3 characters long
    //username and password cannot be same

    //start the validation

    //check the username
    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $errors['username1'] = "Required fields";
    }

    else if (strlen($username)<6 ) {
        $errors['username2'] = "Username should at least 6 characters long";
    }

    else if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{3,20}$/i', $username)) {
        $errors['username3'] = "Username should contain letters and numbers only.";
    }

    //check the password
    if (empty($_POST['password'])){
        $errors['password1'] ="Required fields";
    }
    else if (strlen($password) <8) {
        $errors['password2'] ="Password should at least 8 characters long";
    }

    else if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,20}$/', $password)){
        $errors['password3'] ="Password should contain at least 1 upper-case,1 lower-case,numbers ";
    }

    //check the password confirmation
    if(empty($cpassword)) {
        $errors["cpassword2"] = "Must confirm your password to proceed";
    }

    if($password != $cpassword){
        $errors['cpassword1']="Password do not match";
    }

    //check whether username or password is same
    if($username == $password){
        $errors['sameuserpass'] ="Username and password cannot be same";
    }


    //check the email
    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        $errors['email1'] = "Required fields";
    }

    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors['email3'] ="Please enter a vaild email address";
    }

    //check the errors
    if(count($errors) == 0){

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='$username'");
    $query1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT*FROM user WHERE Email='$email'");
       if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
           $errors['userexist'] ="Username already exists";
       } 

       else if(mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0){
           $errors['emailexist'] = "Email already already exists";
       }

       else {
            //HASHING THE PASSWORD
           $password = md5($password);

            $queryinsert= "INSERT INTO user(Username,Password,Email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
            mysqli_query($con,$queryinsert);

            header("Location:login.php");
       }

    }
}
```

login.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');

    session_start();

    $errors=array();

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    $password = htmlentities(md5($_POST['password']));

    if($email&&$password){

        //declare variable

        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' ");
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        //when user correct input,check the data 
        if($numrows !== 0) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $dbemail=$row['Email'];
                $dbpassword=$row['Password'];
            }


            if($dbemail === $email&&$dbpassword === $password)
            {
                $_SESSION['email']="$email";
                header('Location:user.html');
                exit;
            }

            else
            {
                $errors['notcorrect'] = "Email or password not correct";
            }
        } 
        //when insert wrong data
        else{
            $errors['notexists'] = "This email doesn't exists";
        }
    }
    //when user didnt enter anything
    else{
        $errors['nothing'] = "Please enter your email and password";
    }
}

?>
```

I successfully store the password that hashed into the database,but the problem is cant login again although the email address and password is correct.Any idea?

Comment: remove that htmlentities function and check $password = md5($_POST['password']);

Comment: So, what is a type of the md5 column?

Comment: fix it in login.php there??@AVM

Comment: @sectus wat you mean ya??

Comment: @ken yes on your login page.

Comment: MD5 isn't suitable for password-hashing. You should choose a stronger hashing function, or better yet, and off-the-shelf solution for password management.

Comment: @ken, do you know about types of mysql columns? Please, show create table for us.

Comment: You're also completely misusing `htmlentities`. That's for outputting HTML. You're working with input, on its way to the database. You need to sanitize your inputs with `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @AVM sir,i tried,but still cant login...is successfully hash the password and insert to the database,but still cant login back by using the same email and password

Comment: @sectus the column is just id,Username,Password,and Email,4 coloum in the database...

Comment: @meagar means that I need to change the htmlentities($_POST['email']); to mysqli_real_string_escape($_POST['email']); instead??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

signup.php

```
include ('config.php');

$errors=array();   

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$cpassword=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cpassword']);
//not empty
//at least 3 characters long
//username and password cannot be same

//start the validation

//check the username
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
    $errors['username1'] = "Required fields";
}

else if (strlen($username)<6 ) {
    $errors['username2'] = "Username should at least 6 characters long";
}

else if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{3,20}$/i', $username)) {
    $errors['username3'] = "Username should contain letters and numbers only.";
}

//check the password
if (empty($_POST['password'])){
    $errors['password1'] ="Required fields";
}
else if (strlen($password) <8) {
    $errors['password2'] ="Password should at least 8 characters long";
}

else if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,20}$/', $password)){
    $errors['password3'] ="Password should contain at least 1 upper-case,1 lower-case,numbers ";
}

//check the password confirmation
if(empty($cpassword)) {
    $errors["cpassword2"] = "Must confirm your password to proceed";
}

if($password != $cpassword){
    $errors['cpassword1']="Password do not match";
}

//check whether username or password is same
if($username == $password){
    $errors['sameuserpass'] ="Username and password cannot be same";
}


//check the email
if (empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors['email1'] = "Required fields";
}

else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errors['email3'] ="Please enter a vaild email address";
}

//check the errors
if(count($errors) == 0){

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='$username'");
$query1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT*FROM user WHERE Email='$email'");
   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
       $errors['userexist'] ="Username already exists";
   } 

   else if(mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0){
       $errors['emailexist'] = "Email already already exists";
   }

   else {
        //HASHING THE PASSWORD
       $password = md5($password);

        $queryinsert= "INSERT INTO user(Username,Password,Email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
        mysqli_query($con,$queryinsert);

        header("Location:login.php");
   }

}
}
```

login.php

```
include('config.php');

session_start();

$errors=array();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
$password  = md5($password);
if($email&&$password){

    //declare variable

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' ");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    //when user correct input,check the data 
    if($numrows != 0) {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $dbemail=$row['Email'];
            $dbpassword=$row['Password'];
        }


        if($dbemail == $email && $dbpassword == $password)
        {
            $_SESSION['email']="$email";
            header('Location:user.html');
            exit;
        }

        else
        {
            $errors['notcorrect'] = "Email or password not correct";
        }
    } 
    //when insert wrong data
    else{
        $errors['notexists'] = "This email doesn't exists";
    }
}
//when user didnt enter anything
else{
    $errors['nothing'] = "Please enter your email and password";
}
}
```

Comment: it appear as "mysqli_real_escape_string need 2 parameter,1 is given" for all the mysqli_real_secape_string here...

Comment: I really like to know,what should i put for another parameter for this function "mysqli_real_secape_string" here @AVM

Comment: @ken need to specifies the MySQL connection,Updated the code.check this for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @avm..bro the code still dont work..is can store the password to the database with hash,but cant login using the same password that enter before.is it any idea to solve this?

Comment: @ken is it showing any error? try to echo your query and check whether you are getting result or not on login page.

Comment: is doesn't show any error,just cannot login and show the validation that i set before "Email or password not correct"..

Comment: this is the problem,i also dont know where the problem is,quite struggling

Comment: @ken check your table field names correct or not ie $row['Email']; try to print the result and check.

Comment: ya.is correct.. $row['Email'] and $row['Password'] is exactly the same with the table field there

Comment: i testing by echo it out..is display the data in the database,but i cant login to by entering the email and password that i sign up before...

Comment: @ken your Email field in table is unique right? i think its just password mismatch.try to sign up as a new user with a simple password and check

Comment: ya..the email field is unique..i just check by signing up the simple password..i re-enter it in login.php,is only shown"Email or password is not correct" which i set as validation earlier..and i already modify the code that you show me.

Comment: and the password is store successfully with hash,but the cant login using the same password that sign up before..that's why,i stuck here

Comment: @ken what's the datatype of your Password field in table? also try to echo the md5 password on login page and check whether its the same in db or not

Comment: is works ady.YEAHHHHHHHHHHH...is solve the problem...thank you so much

Comment: actually the problem is I set the password field to 30 character,so let 2 more character didnt store into the database,so everytime validation is doesnt match..after change the field character,is all correct already..thanks so much..is light my day..

Comment: thanks so much for your time,really appreciated for your help..tq

Answer (score 0):

This line?

```
if($dbemail === $email&&$dbpassword === $password)
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
if($dbemail == $email&&$dbpassword == $password)
```

**Edit:**

And did you change your original password to a md5 hash or re-register

If you need a hash for your Db password - This -> `2aefc34200a294a3cc7db81b43a81873` will change your password to **admins**

**Edit 2:**

And I do recommend that you don't use md5 but this instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: sir,pls help me..i dont know where the problem is

Comment: sir at 1st,i md5($password) at signup.php,after there,i cant login,although i already at $password=md5($password) in login.php...

Comment: can you tell me where to fix it?? @David